# Connector Issues Between Tableau and ADLS2

Tags: azure, tableau-api, azure-data-lake, tableau-desktop, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am having issues connecting our ADLS2 environment to Tableau.

I am able to connect to ADLS using the ‘ADLS Gen2 > File URL’ connection type but not the ‘ADLS Gen2 > Browse’ connection type.

We have a .parquet file in there that we want to read and that is not one of the file extension options for the File URL connection type. The connection and access seem to be valid since we are able to read files directly from it using the ‘File URL’ connection so we are unsure what is causing the issue.

We receive the error message: "Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 was unable to process this request. Please report this problem to Tableau." But they haven't been very helpful so far. I was hoping someone else might have run into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 was unable to process this request. Please report this problem to Tableau."
```

If the service principal or user doesn’t have permissions to read or perform the operations, you will get the above error. To resolve the error, add `storage data reader` or `storage data owner` role to the account as follows:

Step 1: Go to IAM of storage account, click on `Add`, and select `Add role assignment` as shown below:

[image]

Step 2: Search for the role and select it as shown below:

[image]

Step 3: Select the account or user as mentioned below:

[image]

After successful role assignment, you will be able to read files or list the files in the container. For more information, you can refer to [this](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_azure_data_lake_gen2.htm?_gl=1*1taebhd*_ga*MTcyOTk1OTA5MS4xNjc0MDIxMDcx*_ga_8YLN0SNXVS*MTcwMjM3Nzk0My40LjEuMTcwMjM3ODMwOC4wLjAuMA..#about-azure-storage-accounts).